# Importing new Excel worksheet rows to MS Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a table in MS Access that is periodically updated. 
After these updates occur, an exportion is done, so i can get a excel worksheet with the entire table updated.

But now I need to do the inverse. Some people will open this document and add lines manually to it, and I need to find some way to append these new lines to a Access table, with an identifier to say if it was inputed manually or not.

My table consists in a "Student" database. Each line corresponds to a "Name", so when someone adds a new name manually in the worksheet, there is a new student in it, so I need its row to go to the database in a new table. I also need those students that are inputed manually to be updated if they change, somehow.

How could I do that in Access? Some example follows below:

**Access table - Table 1**

```
      Name       |   Country   |   Grades   |   IDNumber    |  Identifier
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Scott            |    USA      | 8, 9, 10   |     1000      |  Automatic
Wolverine        |  Indonesia  | 2, 5, 7    |     2000      |  Automatic
Nightcrawler     |   Brazil    | 10, 0, 6   |     3000      |  Automatic
Jean Grey        |   China     | 10, 10, 10 |     4000      |  Automatic
Bobby            |   China     | 8, 7, 10   |     5000      |  Automatic
Kitty            |    USA      | 9, 9, 9    |     6000      |  Automatic
```

**Excel sheet exported from the Access table:**

```
      Name       |   Country   |   Grades   |   IDNumber    |  Identifier
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Scott            |    USA      | 8, 9, 10   |     1000      |  Automatic
Wolverine        |  Indonesia  | 2, 5, 7    |     2000      |  Automatic
Nightcrawler     |   Brazil    | 10, 0, 6   |     3000      |  Automatic
Jean Grey        |   China     | 10, 10, 10 |     4000      |  Automatic
Bobby            |   China     | 8, 7, 10   |     5000      |  Automatic
Kitty            |    USA      | 9, 9, 9    |     6000      |  Automatic
```

**Excel sheet with adicional data that needs to be imported to the Access table:**

```
      Name       |   Country   |   Grades   |   IDNumber    |  Identifier
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Scott            |    USA      | 8, 9, 10   |     1000      |  Automatic
Wolverine        |  Indonesia  | 2, 5, 7    |     2000      |  Automatic
Nightcrawler     |   Brazil    | 10, 0, 6   |     3000      |  Automatic
Jean Grey        |   China     | 10, 10, 10 |     4000      |  Automatic
Bobby            |   China     | 8, 7, 10   |     5000      |  Automatic
Kitty            |    USA      | 9, 9, 9    |     6000      |  Automatic
Tempest          |    Spain    | 10, 9, 2   |     7000      |  Manual <-- Who added will add the word "Manual" to it!
Magneto          |    USA      | 8, 0, 9    |     8000      |  Manual
Lizard           |    India    | 1, 3, 6    |     9000      |  Manual
```

**Table with new values present in the worksheet appended to it - Table 2:**

```
      Name       |   Country   |   Grades   |   IDNumber    |  Identifier  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tempest          |    Spain    | 10, 9, 2   |     7000      |  Manual 
Magneto          |    USA      | 8, 0, 9    |     8000      |  Manual
Lizard           |    India    | 1, 3, 6    |     9000      |  Manual
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Linked Table in Access that points to the Excel spreadsheet.

[Link to data in Excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/import-or-link-to-data-in-an-excel-workbook-HA001219419.aspx#BMlinktodata)

Then, you can create a query in Access that extracts rows in the Excel data that do not appear in the corresponding Access table

Access table:

[image: AccessTable.png]

Excel sheet:

[image: ExcelData.png]

Linked Table in Access:

[image: LinkedTable.png]

Query design:

[image: QueryDesign.png]

Query results:

[image: QueryResults.png]

Comment: Thanks, @Gord. Is there a way to append a fixed value to a column "identifier" (created to identify if the data came manually or not) that says "Manual" for each of the lines that are found? Like a "Manual" value in the Gord row?

Comment: @ZeldaElf You could do something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uy7Aw.png).

Comment: Whoa, nice! I will do this. If I want to create these "Automatic" in the access tables (supossing all "Identifier" values are still null), it's easy?

Comment: @ZeldaElf It should be pretty straightforward. Give it a try, and if you run into difficulty with a specific aspect of the process then ask a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Ok, that's right. I will check it and maybe post a new question later. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could work with Linked Tables (Importing the excel as a Linked Table, not data). That would cause it to reflect the changes made in the excel document directly into your Access environment.

Then you could run a simple sql statement whenever you desire, as such:

```
Insert Into [Students]([Name],[Country],[Grades],[IDNumber])
Select [Name],[Country],[Grades],[IDNumber] from [LinkedTable] 
Where [IDNumber] Not In (Select [IDNumber] from [Students])
```

Assuming that IDNumber is the primary key.